# Delete first Line of a JavaFx Textarea

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

Hello I want to delete the first line of a JavaFx textarea.
I set a TextFormatter on my Textarea and i want to delete the first line, when more then 20 lines are in it:

```
private <T> TextFormatter<T> createTextFormatter() {

    final IntegerProperty lines = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);


    return new TextFormatter<>(change -> {
        if (change.isAdded()) {
            if (change.getText().indexOf('\n') > -1) {
                lines.set(lines.get() + 1);
            }
            if (lines.get() > 20) {
                //TODO
                //delete first row
            }
        }
        return change;
    });
}
```

II would be glad if someone could help

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

overriding TextArea's replaceText method and a check for line count than delete first line if it exeeds 20 lines seems working,

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FixedLineCountTextAreaTry extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Try to enter me more than 20 lines...");
        TextArea ta = new TextArea() {
            @Override
            public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
                super.replaceText(start, end, text);
                while(getText().split("\n", -1).length > 20) {
                    int fle = getText().indexOf("\n");
                    super.replaceText(0, fle+1, "");
                }
                positionCaret(getText().length());
            }
        };

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(ta);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work if you copy text with multiple lines and paste it into the text area... you may need to delete more than one line at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If u means that new line is \n this code will works fine.

```
        String array[] = textArea.getText().split("\n");
        String textToSet = "";
        for(int i=1; i<array.length; i++){
            textToSet+=array[i] + "\n";
        }
        textArea.setText(textToSet);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution based on a text formatter.

```
TextFormatter<String> { change ->
            if (change.isAdded) {
                val maxByteSize = 1.5e+6 //15 mb
                if (change.controlNewText.length <= maxByteSize) change
                else {
                    val textArea = change.control as TextArea
                    val end = if (textArea.length > change.text.length) change.text.length else textArea.length
                    textArea.replaceText(0, end, "")
                    change.setRange(textArea.length, textArea.length)
                    change
                }
            } else {
                change
            }
}
```

Comment: The snipped is Kotlin syntax :P

Comment: hmm ... from [api doc of textFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.Change.html): "Note that you should never modify the state of the control directly from within the formatter handler"  ... which you do by replacing the text in the underlying textArea (or am I mis-reading the kotlin?)